# Clifford-Mackey theory, references

Tags: rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures

I am working on a problem related to the local Langlands correspondence and I am interested in certain smooth representations of locally profinite groups (in particular of the Weil group of a local field). I want to study them using elementary Clifford-Mackey theory. Can someone suggest me some references for Clifford-Mackey theory in this context?

Thanks in advance, AYK

Comment: What have you looked at?  Is what you want not in Bushnell-Henniart?  (I don't remember exactly what's in there.)

Comment: They usually refer to it as standard Mackey theory in their works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standard Mackey theory (also called the Mackey machine), I found [Kaniuth and Taylor](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/induced-representations-locally-compact-groups) useful. Standard Clifford theory is discussed in Curtis and Reiner (Methods of representation theory II).